# Telegram get a list of all the groups i have admin privileges in

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

i am finding it difficult figuring out all the groups that i have admin privileges in so that i can add my bot. there are about 300 groups. is there any user level api or a 3rd party api to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Telethon, you can check whether you have admin rights or not by this code:

```
client = TelegramClient("session", API_ID, API_HASH)
await client.connect()

dialogs = await client.get_dialogs()
for dialog in dialogs:
    if not isinstance(dialog.entity, User):
        if dialog.entity.admin_rights is not None:
            print(dialog.entity.admin_rights)
```

Comment: this definitely is from ChatGPT

Comment: No, this code was part of my Telethon project.  Are there any errors?

Comment: @Megasrx yes. In the voice of Captain Jack Sparrow, there should be an `import` somewhere.